# Using JSoup with Android Studio to collect information from website or rss feed

Tags: java, android, parsing, rss, jsoup

I'm learning to use JSoup (slowly) to parse the source code of a website, but I feel myself nearing the end of my rope.  That is, I'm not entirely sure what methods I should be looking into.

In theory, I want to develop an app that sifts through a particular search page (ie. Google, Monster, Craigslist, eBay, etc.) and pulls out certain pieces of data.  This data might be on the first page, but it could be 10+ pages down the list (in Google, obviously it could be hundreds).  Whether it's a search result (Google), a job posting (Monster), or an item for sale (Craigslist/eBay), how do I go about getting this done?

I didn't know about JSoup until recently.  And I'm not "stuck" on using it.  But, my research has led me to believe that using JSoup will give me the desired result.  So, I'm trying to learn how to use it to do what I want.  (if anyone knows any extensive beginner tutorials, let me know)

So how should I go about doing this?  I know it's a vague questions, but I have a goal and I'm not sure how I get to it.

I've also contemplated using/searching RSS feeds when available (ie. Craigslist).  Is this also possible and easier or harder than attempted to pull straight from the site/source code?

On top of that, I want to be able to send the user notifications if new information has presented itself (new items for sale on Craigslist/eBay, new job on Monster, etc.) A separate topic I know, one that I can figure out I'm sure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is a little vague so I'll try to cover as much as possible.
Jsoup is a `HTML/XHTML parser` library. This means that it can make a `GET` or a `POST` request to a certain url and get the content generated by the server. Then it parses this content to build a `DOM` representation using java objects.

The problem is your examples. You mention `Google` and `Monster`. As fas as I know these sites use `Ajax` in order to retrieve the content from the server. They use `javascript` in order to generate dynamic content. `Jsoup` cannot handle `javascript` generated content. This is due to its inability to execute `javascript`. It can certainly "see" it since it's included in the response of the server, but it perceives it as simple text, not code. The browsers can handle this kind of content since the include a `javascript` execution engine.

In general is safer/better/easier to get the content from an `API` of the source. Does it provide `rss feed` or an `API`? Then use that. For instance `Google` [provides a way](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) to programmatically execute search queries.

If the source doesn't provide a programmatic way of accessing it, then you can parse the content using `Jsoup` if and only if the content is static. In order to determine if the content is static or is being generated by `javascript` then visit the site you want to parse and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>. The mesh of `HTML` is what `Jsoup` will receive when you make a request to the site. If the content you need is not included in there, then the content is dynamic. In that case, you must use a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser), which is a library/framework that, among others, includes a `javacript` execution engine. This way you can simulate the browser 100%.

As far as tutorials go, [this](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) will cover all your needs regarding `Jsoup`. If the content is `javacript` generated, then you can retrieve it by using a headless browser, and then use `Jsoup` by parsing the already retrieved content just for parsing and not getting the content.

The material I provided is sufficient for continuing your research. In order to get better information then you must be specific about the problem you are facing.

**Update**

Check [selenium for android](http://selendroid.io/) and [selendroid](http://selendroid.io/mobileWeb.html)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide so much information.  I do think that it was helpful, and I do understand what you're saying.  I had been going through some of the code of the site(s) that I want to pull from, and I had already begun to realize that they used Javascript, and that it might be a problem.  It seems as though my next step is to look into headless browsers, though I'm not sure where to go from there at the moment, or how using one would change my situation.  That part I don't understand.  Again, thanks so much!

Comment: Check my update. And don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem. Again though, I suggest that you look for official APIs first and then consider scraping the content.

Comment: Are there other methods to parsing, or pulling from in some other way, from a site like we mentioned, one that uses Javascript to produce its results?  Also, my apologies for such a vague post, what more information would you need to help direct me?

Comment: I've been specific as to what you need to research. Check the answer again as I've updated it. When you do that, and you have written some code, you can ask specifically for a problem you might be facing. There is no golden solution here. You read all the material and you try something. If you get stuck then you can ask something specific next time.